# Back out of a directory for a URI in java

Tags: java, directory, uri

I'm trying to make an app that opens a static webpage.  Just a pilot for a bigger project.  At the moment I'm getting the default browser to open fine and the test page loads up.  However, it will only work if the html file is in the directory as the .class file.  How can I back out of the directory the class file is in and enter another directory?  Similar to a cmd cd ....\whatever command.

Thanks

Comment: did you get it resolved?

Comment: Hey @Mr D, thanks for asking.  As this is a self contained little app I'm working on that doesn't need to be live I've just taken the whole static file directory and wrapped it up as a self extracting .exe for the client.  They install it, the directory tree is preserved and it auto runs the welcome html file post install.  That way I can just use the ../ for relative pathways within the app itself.  Slightly cumbersome buts serves it's purpose.

Answer (score 3):

To go back in the directory tree, use `../`:

`../Test1/Example.txt`

Or you can also do:

```
currentDir.getParentFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey why dont you try to put your pages in WebContent directly and hit those pages by hitting
    "htp://localhost/your page name.htm>"

You can navigate by usign hyperlinks. See W3C School tutorials.
No need to think how to go back. Links can take you to any where.

If inside A folder inside WebContent/ROOT, you can just hit "htp://localhost/A/your page name.htm>"

From a page to another you can also refer through hyperlinks.